# How can I create a flexible medium for accessing png/bmp files with code so my code will run in Eclipse, as well as after it is exported?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making an application that searches the screen for a specific image. I read the picture (file) I am scanning for and convert it to a buffered image, then to an `int[]` so I can process it faster. I also use the robot class to take a screenshot and convert to an `int[]`.

While running code in Eclipse and having the files in the source folder, I don't have any problems. But after exporting my code to a runnable `jar` file, my scanning methods no longer work. I think it might have something to do with compression because my pictures need to be exactly how they were taken.

The only success I have had with a "finished format" is by exporting the `jar` normally, and using a folder in the same directory called `images` to hold the files. Using this code:

```
File img = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "Close.bmp");
```

When running directly from eclipse I can simply do this:

```
File img = new File(src/Close.bmp);
```

Any suggestions? Maybe some tips/settings on exporting jars?

Answer (score 0):

You have various options:

- probably the easiest is to put the [image in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java), i.e. deploy it with your class files, probably within a jar file. The drawback is that you can't replace the image (as long as you don't want your user to fiddle with the classpath)
- place it relative to the `user.dir` as you have done, in this case you need to understand what the user.dir actually is: The working directory from which your application got started. It will differ depending on how you start it.
- another option is to use a path relative to `user.home` which is your home directory.